# Padding affects backgrond color of link

Tags: hyperlink, background-color

I have padding on images and the padding affects the image link because there is a black line
Style

```
    a:link{background-color:black}
    img{padding:20px}
```

Html

```
      <a href="Sample"><img src="blank"></a>
```

So in Simple terms there is a black line coming from the image and I want to get rid of it. I can't get rid of the styled link because I use it for other links

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `black`, use `transparent` or `none`

#### SNIPPET

```css
.tran {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.none {
  background-color: none;
}
img {
  padding: 20px
}
```

```html
<a href="#/" class='tran'>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/o1RbMvI.png">
</a>
<a href="#/" class='none'>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/o1RbMvI.png">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want specific style for one link, but you don't want it to affect the others or be affected by the others, I would set up a specific class for the links you want to have a `background-color: black;` and then a separate class for the link that you don't want affected by it. zer00ne provides a sufficient answer for this. Just add `class="tran"` or whatever you want to name them into your links that you want to be connected together with whatever style you use in `.tran{}`, as shown in his answer. Play around with grouping things into classes and using the classes to style more specific elements in your CSS. Best of luck!

in css file:

```
        .black{background-color:black;}

         img{padding:20px;}
```

HTML:

```
    <p>
        <a href="Sample" class="not-black"><img src="blank"></a>
        <a href="Sample" class="black"><img src="blank"></a>
    </p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it wasn't what I was looking for but I'll just change it to classes to make it easier instead

Comment: What are you looking for exactly: maybe I can still help? The black line exists because you're targeting all of the links. If you don't want to target all of the links (i.e. don't want a black line behind one of them) you need to set up a way to identify a specific link (class) and target it separately.

Comment: Are you asking how to setup a link to only the image and not the padded area surrounding it?

Comment: Yea thats what I mean